# Why is 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout' omittable?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

I notice that I can comment out `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'` without any errors though I use ConstraintLayout in my app.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
}
```

Why is it ok? Does the com.google.android.material library also contain constraintLayout?

Comment: you should be able to test it, if that were to be the case, remove both material and constraint layout. if it then fails, then it's included in material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indeed coming from [`com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material/1.3.0) - but when you don't declare it explicitly, you'll build against version `2.0.1` - instead of the current version `2.0.4`.

Just run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see that it will resolve a different version.

---

Disclaimer: I'm not exactly sure why these dependencies are rather dated
... but generally one could exclude them, so that one has to provide them:

```
implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0") {
    exclude group: "androidx.annotation"       // 1.0.1 < 1.1.0
    exclude group: "androidx.appcompat"        // 1.1.0 < 1.2.0
    exclude group: "androidx.constraintlayout" // 2.0.1 < 2.0.4
    exclude group: "androidx.core"             // 1.2.0 < 1.3.2
    exclude group: "androidx.fragment"         // 1.0.0 < 1.3.0
    exclude group: "androidx.lifecycle"        // 2.0.0 < 2.3.0
    exclude group: "androidx.recyclerview"     // 1.0.0 < 1.1.0
    exclude group: "androidx.transition"       // 1.2.0 < 1.4.0
}

implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.2"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.transition:transition:1.4.0"
```

That's at least what Maven Central says; I'm assuming no side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` contain constraintLayout.